# Neo4j / Cypher - Conditional counting in Return Statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Currently I got the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (topic:TopicNode)-[r]-(article:ArticleNode)-[b]->(author:AuthorNode)
MATCH (topic)-[v]->(source:SourceNode)
WHERE  r.relevancy > 0.002
RETURN topic, count(DISTINCT article), count(DISTINCT author), count(DISTINCT source)
```

Which is working fine and delivers the expected results for each topic.

Now I want to get the following additional information: the count of articles of each topic with a positive sentiment (e.g. `article.sentiment > 0`) and negative sentiment.

Is there a way to add conditional statements to a count operator?

For example like this:

```
RETURN count(article.sentiment > 0)
```

Because this did not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this using list comprehensions:

```
MATCH (topic:TopicNode)-[r]-(article:ArticleNode)-[b]->(author:AuthorNode) 
MATCH (topic)-[v]->(source:SourceNode) 
WHERE  r.relevancy > 0.002 
WITH topic, count(DISTINCT article) AS articlesCount, count(DISTINCT author) AS authorsCount, count(DISTINCT source) AS sourceCount, collect(DISTINCT article) AS articles
RETURN topic, articlesCount, authorsCount, sourceCount, size([x IN articles WHERE x.sentiment > 0 | x ]) AS positiveSentiment, size([x IN articles WHERE x.sentiment < 0 | x ]) AS negativeSentiment
```

Here, we collect articles in a list and then use list comprehensions, to filter out the articles with positive and negative sentiments and calculate their counts. Try it out.